# Does JSP page know its own file name?

Tags: jsp

Other then putting a comment or a hidden variable as part of own JSP page, is it possible programmatically to find out what it is?

If so, how can I reference own file name inside JSP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
${pageContext.request.servletPath}
```

to obtain the part of the request/forward URI which matched the `JspServlet`. This works regardless of if the JSP is been requested standalone or been forwarded by a front controller servlet.

In JSP files which are been included by another JSP, instead use

```
${requestScope['javax.servlet.include.servlet_path']}
```

You can't really obtain the JSP original file name in any way as it's been generated to a servlet class. You can however obtain the ([simple](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName%28%29)) class name of the generated servlet class as follows:

```
${pageContext.page['class'].simpleName}
```

When using Jasper as JSP compiler (as is been used in Tomcat and clones), this defaults to `filename_jsp` (with underscore instead of period). This may or may not be sufficient as it tight-couples the code to a specific container.